# Target div if it's string contains exact number and exact amount of characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string inside an div and I want to target this div if the number is 0 - and if its the only character. The currency symbol changes so I can't use that.

As soon as the string is €1, €10 etc and don't want to target it - only if its 0 and one number in the string.

I want to use a if variable or something similar since I need to append and add a class when the string is matched. Something like:

```
if( $code to match the string )
{
 $( "em.headcartsum" ).addClass( "hide" );
}

<span><em id="headercartsum">€0</em></span>
```

Comment: your element does not have a class name as per your selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with regex:

```js
$('em.headercartsum').filter(function() {
  return /^\D0$/.test($.trim($(this).text()));
}).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><em class="headercartsum">€0</em></span>
<span><em class="headercartsum">$10</em></span>
<span><em class="headercartsum">$0</em></span>
```

The regex `/^\D0$/` checks if the string contains only a non-digit character(currency symbol) followed by a zero.

Comment: @Xeptor Check Demo, I've changed the id to class, as there'll be multiple elements

Comment: hmm seems like it shoudl work but its not. Cant figure out why.. .

Comment: @Xeptor Can you please create live demo on jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry! It does work, my mistake. that is great! i was wondering about the regex for this - will read up on that. thanks again!

Comment: @Xeptor For regex see the last line, `\D` matches a single non-digit character, `0` matches zero, and `^` and `$` makes sure that the string contains only the specified pattern and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use a regex match:

```
if($('#headercartsum').text().match(/€0/)) {
    $('em.headcartsum').addClass('hide');
}
```

Comment: _"The currency symbol changes so I can't use that."_

Answer (score 0):

As your element does have an *id* then you can use `.toggleClass(class, condition)` case:

```js
$('.headercartsum').each(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hide', $(this).text().match(/(\d)/)[0] == 0);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span><em class="headercartsum">€10</em></span>
<span><em class="headercartsum">€0</em></span>
<span><em class="headercartsum">€10</em></span>
```

Comment: See if you like this `$('.headercartsum').toggleClass(function() {
  return $(this).text().match(/(\d+)$/)[0] == 0 ? 'hide' : '';
});`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number with parseInt like this :

```
if(parseInt($("#headercartsum").text().trim()) === 0){
 // Execute your code here.
}
```